# Magento 2 layered navigation with checkbox with multi select

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, multiselect-attribute

I would like to implement layered navigation with **checkbox** instead of links in my Magento 2 project.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to go with smile elastic search suite which comes with many more extra features including multi-select layered nav. It is free and open source :-) I am using this in one of my projects and it is working perfectly. Had to install elastic search with some extra modules which provide more accurate search results.

1. Check https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite
2. Demo http://demo.magento-elastic-suite.io/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write this yourself, you could start by looking at an existing implementation such as this on GitHub:

https://github.com/NikZh/magento2-multiple-layered-navigation