# Can magento2 layered navigation support multiply value on same filter?

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, multiselect-attribute

For example, i would like to filter products in both "Red" and "Blue"  color, (where color is a dropdown attribute) 
can i tick both value within the same filter?

Comment: provide your magento version

Comment: Check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124679/magento-2-layered-navigation-with-checkbox-with-multi-select/170639#170639

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible but using third party extension as it is not inbuilt in Magento or Magento 2. So you can integrate such third party extension which allows multiple selection for single attribute in layered navigation.